# Extending Cauchy Goursat from triangles to simply connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis

In this page [Cauchy Integral Theorem](http://planetmath.org/CauchyIntegralTheorem.html), the three Cauchy integral theorems are presented. The first is about simply connected domains and the second is a generalisation of the 1st that includes removable singularities. The third is the Cauchy Goursat theorem regarding triangles or rectangles. At one point (just before the 3rd theorem) it writes:

> "Goursat's argument makes use of rectangular contour (many authors use triangles though), **but the extension to an arbitrary simply-connected domain is relatively straight-forward**"

How is that extension straight-forward? What is the proof of that? 
In other words how can I prove the 1st theorem for the 3rd (using the triangle version of Cauchy Goursat prefferably) and then how do I prove that the 1st theorem implies the 2nd?
($3\Rightarrow 1\Rightarrow 2$). It would be preferrable if someone linked a pdf file containg the proofs I am asking for. Also note that I am looking for elementary self contained answers that don't invole a lot of topological notions but basic topology. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(3) \Rightarrow (1)$: [Proof Cauchy-Goursat-Theorem (Theorem 15.2)](http://de.scribd.com/doc/82199387/13/Cauchy%E2%80%93Goursat-Theorem)

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$: It's a consequence of the residue theorem - probably you'll find a proof (using Cauchy's Theorem) in every book about analytical functions (or here: [Proof 1](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnicafolder/ica10.pdf)/[Proof 2 (short one)](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/residuecalculus/ResidueCalcTheorem.1.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for the $(3)\Rightarrow (1)$ proof, it is exactly what I asked. Now the $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ theorem is necessary (to my knowledge) to prove Cauchy's Integral Fomula and thus the residue theorem...

Comment: Ah, okay, you want to do it the other way round. In this case, $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ is a simple consequence of [Riemann's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) (since the function is bounded in a neighborhood of the singularities, the singularities are removable.)

Comment: Wait a minute. In the proof of $(3)\Rightarrow (1)$ the 3rd step (the one I am asking for) is pretty much omitted...

Comment: That's true, but I doubt that there is a more detailed proof (especially since there are a lot of other (in my oppinion easier) ways to proof this theorem). But anyway: You can cover im $\gamma$ by arbritrary small squares and obtain a polygonal contour $\Gamma$ arbritary close to $\gamma$ (I tried to draw a [picture](http://www.fkuehn.de/download/ct.png) ). Since $f$ is continuous it works fine.